# Como substituir tags html e salvar em um novo arquivo

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, automatização

Estou tentando verificar um arquivo *.html*, remover algumas tags e criar um novo arquivo com as alterações feitas.

No método que estou utilizando no momento (js, gulp) eu acabo fazendo vários replaces em cadeia, acredito que esse não seja a melhor maneira, gostaria de saber um método melhor de fazer isso.

Segue o código da minha task atual:

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var fs = require("fs");

gulp.task("fixes", function(done) {
  var conteudo;

  fs.readFile("index.html", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    conteudo = data;

    var t = data.replace(/(<body>|<\/body>)/g, "");
    var final = t.replace(/<meta charset="utf-8">/, "");

    fs.writeFile("dist.html", final, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  });

  console.log("Novo arquivo criado!");
  done();
});
```